# Сравнение координат родственных элементов на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Есть неопределённое количество родственных элементов на странице. Они создаются пользователем. Пользователь может работать с одним из них (передвигать, изменять размер). Как делать сравнение элемента над которым проводятся операции, с другими уже созданными элементами? Сравнивать нужно их позиции, а именно левую и правую стороны. Это нужно для того, чтобы запретить элементам накладываться друг на друга, будь то при перемещении, или же при изменении размера.

Есть мысль что надо собирать при создании позиции элементов в массив, а затем сравнивать рабочий элемент с остальными. Но если загнать в массив координаты при создании, то как они будут обновляться при изменении позиции элемента, не понятно. Так же непонятно как сравнить текущий элемент с элементами массива. Кода в данном направлении пока нет,. не вижу смысла писать переменную с пустым массивом - но это пока все наработки. Если нужно - могу дать код изменения размера, и изменения положения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут нужен скорее ассоциативный массив.

1. Создаем объект хранилище: `var storage = {};`
2. Создаем элемент, присваиваем ему ID.
3. Сохраняем в хранилище данные нашего объекта:

   storage[id] = {
       top: 10,
       left: 30
   }
4. Всё, теперь у вы точно знаете в какой ячейке, чьи данные.

Comment: @lonDen спасибо за ответ. Был бы признателен за пример для пункта 3. На каком этапе и как сохранять в хранилище объекты?

Comment: @Baga, примерно вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/tbtuo86t/

Comment: @lonDen спасибо большое, буду пробовать

Comment: @lonDon все вроде норм, но как делать проверку в цикле, так и не додумался(

Comment: @Baga, проверка делается примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/e4w9p3ow/